# Spreadsheet with language-agnostic networking API

Tags: api, spreadsheet

I'm looking for a spreadsheet that can be controlled from outside, similar to e.g. how LibreOffice can be controlled via the [UNO API](http://api.libreoffice.org/).

I'd like it to have standard manual manipulation functionality - nothing extraordinary, but I'd need things like sorting, filtering, etc.

From the API side, I probably need just the basic data push functionality:

- Programming language agnostic - e.g. some kind of REST service or something simple along those lines
- Preferably Push API - i.e. the client would push data instead of spreadsheet pulling
- Create / delete / display sheet
- Populate data (basic add / remove rows would suffice, even all-or-nothing approach)
- Styling would be a plus, not a deal breaker

Answer (score 2):

[Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/) would seem to meet a lot of your needs:

- Reasonably Full Spreadsheet Functionality
- Multiple APIs [available](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) including [REST](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/), XML & JSON based IRL Fetch
- Bindings such as the python [google-api-python-client](http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/) library
- Push API Yes
- Styling, Sorting, Filtering, etc.
- Populate data including Add, Remove, etc.
- Authorisation with OAUTH/OAUTH2
- Download As: ODF, XMLX, CSV, TSV, Zipped HTML, PDF.